# Relative import of a module within a package

Tags: python, namespaces, python-import

How can I make a module-within-a-package `.adipiscing.lorem_ipsum` available, in a way which **cleanly uses the import system** and **doesn't leave extraneous names unused**?

Given a code base:

```
foo/
    consecteur.py
    adipiscing/
        lorem_ipsum.py
```

The `consecteur` module needs to access the `adipiscing.lorem_ipsum` module.

This is what I want to do:

```python
# consecteur.py

from . import adipiscing.lorem_ipsum

dolor = adipiscing.lorem_ipsum.dolor_sit_amet()
```

That doesn't work; `from . import adipiscing.lorem_ipsum` is a SyntaxError.

### Options that don't satisfy

#### Use implicit relative import

```python
# consecteur.py

import adipiscing.lorem_ipsum

dolor = adipiscing.lorem_ipsum.dolor_sit_amet()
```

This needlessly confuses whether `adipiscing.lorem_ipsum` is an absolute or relative import. The code should instead be explicit when an import is relative.

#### Pull the module out of its namespace package

```python
# consecteur.py

from .adipiscing import lorem_ipsum

dolor = lorem_ipsum.dolor_sit_amet()
```

This loses the valuable information that is conveyed by reading `adipiscing.lorem_ipsum`, especially if `lorem_ipsum` is instead a generic word that *needs* to be contextualised by the `adipiscing` package namespace.

#### Import with a mangled name

```python
# consecteur.py

from .adipiscing import lorem_ipsum as adipiscing_lorem_ipsum

dolor = adipiscing_lorem_ipsum.dolor_sit_amet()
```

This is visually confusing; someone expecting `adipiscing.lorem_ipsum` can easily type that expecting it to work, but that name is not available. Making a confusingly-similar name is not a good solution; neither is making a distinct name, since the whole purpose is to make `adipiscing.lorem_ipsum` available.

This is also ambiguous if one or both of the package or the module names actually have underscores already. If an underscore represents a dot, that becomes indistinguishable from a name that actually contains an underscore.

#### Import the package, try using the module

```python
# consecteur.py

from . import adipiscing

dolor = adipiscing.lorem_ipsum.dolor_sit_amet()
```

This is an AttributeError because `adipiscing.lorem_ipsum` is not available now; a module is not automatically available just by importing the containing package.

#### Import the package, then import the module but never use its name

```python
# consecteur.py

from . import adipiscing
from .adipiscing import lorem_ipsum

dolor = adipiscing.lorem_ipsum.dolor_sit_amet()
```

This hack succeeds, but the import statement `from .adipiscing import lorem_ipsum` declares that we will be using the bare `lorem_ipsum` name.

Since that's not true, static code checkers will (correctly) complain about an unused import. I agree with those code checkers, so I don't just want to silence the warning; I want to avoid the hack and still get the `adipiscing.lorem_ipsum` name available.

So, how can I make the `adipiscing.lorem_ipsum` name available to the code **by that name**, using an **explicit relative import**, **without unused imports**?

Comment: If you are worrying about code checker (i.e. flake8), just append [`# noqa: F401`](https://flake8.readthedocs.io/en/2.0/warnings.html) to the lines and comment why you did it.

Comment: Alternatively just use the full import as that fully disambiguates what the thing is and is much more explicit.

Comment: Alternatively, try to see after `from . import adipiscing`, just do `from adipiscing import lorem_ipsum`, note the lack of leading `.` for `adipiscing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there seems to be no way to do this using the Python import system.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you want is not supported by the Python's interpreter. But you may use `as` as an workaround with *"Pull the module out of its namespace package"*. For example:

```
from .lorem import ipsum as lorem_ipsum

dolor = lorem_ipsum.dolor_sit_amet()
```

Doing this you will get the full context that it is `lorem's ipsum`

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question to show why this is insufficient.